# NextJS Error Boundrys is trigering all the time

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a simple nextJS application using App Router. Now I need a restricted area in the following route: **http://localhost:3000/user/admin_4yell3oubkr/dashboard**

My problem is that the error is triggering every time the page is rendering

I did a custom Hook to check if a user session is true or false and compare the session id with the one in the url:

```js
// hooks/usePermissionCheck.tsx
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export function usePermissionCheck(uid: string): boolean {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  return !!session && (session.user as any).uid === uid;
}
```

Then in my Page aka Dashboard component I check the status of Permission check:

```js
"use client";

// dashboard.tsx
import { usePermissionCheck } from "@/app/hooks/usePermissionCheck";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Dashboard({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const hasPermission = usePermissionCheck(params.id);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false); // Set loading to false after permission check
  }, [hasPermission]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>; // Show a loading indicator
  }

  if (!hasPermission) {
    // Trigger Next.js error handling mechanism
    throw new Error("Unauthorized");
  }

  return <>{/* Render content if user has permission */}</>;
}
```

And here comes the issue:

the if condition is working as excepted. until I add the " throw new Error("Unauthorized"); ".

Now the error is raised every time the page is loaded regardless of the if statement. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better solution to handle errors?

BTW: Im using nextJS Error Boundrys:

```js
// error.tsx
"use client"; // Error components must be Client Components

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Error({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
  reset: () => void;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the error to an error reporting service
    console.error(error);
  }, [error]);

  return (
    <>
      <main className="grid min-h-full place-items-center bg-white px-6 py-24 sm:py-32 lg:px-8">
        <div className="text-center">
          {/* <p className="text-base font-semibold text-indigo-600">404</p> */}
          <h1 className="mt-4 text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl">
            {error.message}
          </h1>
          <p className="mt-6 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
            not logged in
          </p>
          <div className="mt-10 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-6">
            <a
              onClick={
                // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
                () => reset()
              }
              className="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
            >
              back to hime
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">
              contact <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```